# logic for category, subcateory and view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, uiviewcontroller

I ask for your opinion on the management of categories and subcategories within an app that uses a sqlite database.

This is my screen application:

[image]

This is my database scheme SQLITE:

```
table CATEGORY
id_category | parent_id | name
 1            0           television
 2            0           iphone
 3            1           LCD
 4            1           LED
 5            1           PLASMA

table PRODUCTS
id_product | id_category | name
1               3          LCD 22"
2               3          LCD 24"
3               2          IPHONE 4S
```

Now if there are subcategories I must view a subcategory view also else i must view the list of products in the  main category.

I thought of something like:

```
if(parent_id == 0) {
// list products view    
}else{
// subcategory view
}
```

is correct the logic?

Comment: With this logic, how will you identify the subproducts, i doubt on that. some refinement on the logic is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work, especially if you want the flexibility to have multiple levels of subcategories, e.g., mac->desktop->imac->20 inch.

However, if there is only ever a single level of subcategory, you may want to consider just creating three tables, category, subcategory, and product. That way the relationships between the entities is more controlled and less work needs to happen at the code level.

I would suggest keeping the table names "singular" as a standard naming convention. "PRODUCTS" should just be "PRODUCT". This will create more logically-named entities.